# Set picker starting with two digit numbers (from 00) - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have a ForEach inside a picker with numbers from 0 to 20 that shows 0, 1, 2...20 but instead I need to display 00, 01, 02...20. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want your output value to be a `String` to have a `0` in-front, or an `Int` which you can pad zeroes in-front later on? I feel like an `Int` would be more useful.

Comment: I actually have a string that stores the current data picker

Comment: I just feel like you would need to check against each `String` value separately, but it's up to you.

Comment: what's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: My current picker shows the output like this: ForEach(0 ..< 21) { item in Text("\(item)")}

Comment: [New Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63332441/9607863) has shown it best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the normal string formatting `String(format: "%02d", 5)`:

```
@State var num: Int = 0

var body: some View {
   Picker("", selection: $num) {
      ForEach(0..<21) { v in 
         Text(String(format: "%02d", v)) 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Text`'s [`init(_:format:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:)) initializer and `NumberFormatStyleConfiguration.Precision`'s [`integerLength(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatstyleconfiguration/precision/3798917-integerlength) static method in order to display 2-digit numbers in your picker:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Amount", selection: $amount) {
                ForEach(0..<20) {
                    Text(
                        $0,
                        format: .number.precision(.integerLength(2))
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `Text`'s [`init(_:format:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:)), you can format your amount inline using `NumberFormatStyleConfiguration.Precision`'s [`integerLength(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatstyleconfiguration/precision/3798917-integerlength) and [`formatted(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/formatted(_:)-4qd73):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Amount", selection: $amount) {
                ForEach(0..<20) {
                    Text($0.formatted(.number.precision(.integerLength(2))))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as an alternative, you can use `NumberFormatStyleConfiguration.Precision`'s [`integerLength(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatstyleconfiguration/precision/3798918-integerlength) method that accepts a parameter of type `Range`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Amount", selection: $amount) {
                ForEach(0..<120) {
                    Text(
                        $0,
                        format: .number.precision(.integerLength(2...))
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```